# How to generate auto increment in a folder in python?

Tags: python, excel, auto-increment

I am new to Python. Anyone help with how to generate auto-increment like B00001, B00002, B00003...... which can autosave the excel file name with a button in a specific folder.

I have tried with

```
global numXlsx
numXlsx = 1
wb.save(f'invoice/B{numXlsx}.xlsx')
numXlsx += 1
```

But when I click the button for few times with different data, it still keeps overwriting the B1.xlsx file. Anyone help with this :)

Comment: Please extend you problem description beyond "seems like it is not working".

Comment: What does `count(1)` do?

Comment: when you click button, counter starts from value 1 (program starts again), also since argument of `count` is `1`, only 1 file is created (`B1.xlsx`) each time you click button.
Use `count(4)` to get 4 files.
P.S. you should also post the code for `count(...)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the biggest problem you're having is that each button click is re-starting the execution of your python script, so using a global variable won't work since that doesn't persist across executions. In this case, I'd suggest using something like the [pickle module](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) to store and reload your counter value each time you execute your script. Using that module, your solution could look something like this:

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

# creates file if it doesn't exist
myfile = Path("save.p")
myfile.touch(exist_ok=True)

persisted = {}
with (open(myfile, "rb")) as f:
    try:
        persisted = pickle.load(f)
    except EOFError:
        print("file was empty, nothing to load")

# use get() to avoid KeyError if key doesn't exist
if persisted.get('counter') is None:
    persisted['counter'] = 1

wb.save(f"invoice/B{persisted.get('counter')}.xlsx")
persisted['counter'] += 1

# save everything back into the same file to be used next execution
pickle.dump(persisted, open(myfile, "wb"))
```

BONUS: If you want the count to be padded with zeros in the filename, use `persisted.get('counter'):05d` in the curly brackets when saving the file. The `5` indicates you want the resulting value to be at least 5 characters long, so for example `2` would become `00002` and `111` would become `00111`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a global variable and incrementing it everytime.
Try with something like:
(inizialize it to 0)

```
global numXlsx # this is like your counter variable)
wb.save(f'folder/B{numXlsx}.xlsx')
numXlsx += 1 # Incrementing the variable so it does not overwrite the file as your code is doing
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: But it is now still overwriting the file even I have used like numXlxs = 1 and the following u send. Thx a lot btw.

Comment: Can you post the complete code so we can understand better?